# How to get asset URL from field in template

Tags: assets

I'm new to Craft and having a very hard time calling the URL from a field I created called `imagePrimary`

I've read this extensively but still no luck. https://craftcms.com/docs/assets-fields

```
{% include 'header.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% for entry in craft.entries.section('projects').limit(500).find() %}  

<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="row entry feed linked">

        <div class="title"><a href="{{ entry.url }}"><p><span>{{ entry.studio }}</span>{{ entry.title }}</p></a></div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">

            <div class="featured image" style="background-image: url(

                {% for asset in entry.imagePrimary %}
                     {{ asset.url() }}                                  
                {% endfor %}

            )"></div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 secondary">

            <div class="featured image secondary" style="background-image: url()"></div>
            <div class="featured image secondary" style="background-image: url()"></div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}

{% include 'footer.html' %}
```

Answer (score 9):

Hey Jeremy give this a shot to see if it works (from [craft.assets](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.assets))

```
{% for asset in entry.imagePrimary %}
     <img src="{{ asset.url }}" alt="{{ asset.title }}">                               
{% endfor %}
```

If this doesn't clear it up, I'd double check the field Handle to make sure it's spelled correctly and there is an image within one of your entries.

Comment: Shouldn't `{{ entry.title }}` be `{{ asset.title }}`?

Comment: Yes you are correct. Editing to fix.

Comment: Why is iterating over the asset object necessary? Why doesn't `entry.imagePrimary.url` work?

Comment: Got it - `{{ entry.imagePrimary }}` is an array! When defining an asset field, there is a field to denote how many elements this asset can hold. To access the first element in the array, use `{{ entry.imagePrimary[0].url }}` !!